Xcode Multiple commands produce for GoogleUtilities_Privacy?

The Flutter application is installing into the devices but when i make Archive the build fails and getting these errors
Multiple commands produce '/Users/smartgenx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bpwrmdgyoqyrpydnmdwiwrgtrsjt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities_Privacy.bundle'
AND
Multiple commands produce '/Users/smartgenx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities_Privacy.bundle'

you have 700+ rep please make some effort, there's not even a single sentence in your question

Thanks for comment, I have updated the question
